# Axios post request is not working in Ionic 2

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic-native

I'm trying to get oauth token from my laravel app to my ionic 2 app.But it got error. How to solve it ?
It work fine in browser but when i emulate it it doesn't work.

Login.ts (ionic)

```
getLogin(event) {
    oauth_credentials.username = 'rafsanhashemi@gmail.com';
    oauth_credentials.password = 'secret';
    axios.post(route.oauth_token, JSON.stringify(oauth_credentials), 
    {headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}})
    .then( res => {
        console.log(res)
        this.selectedItem = res.data;
    })
    .catch( err => {
        console.log(err.data)
        this.selectedItem = 'err';
    })
}
```

Error what i got . How to fixed it ?

[image: This is the error]

Answer (score 0):

I advice you to use Angular `HttpClient` https://angular.io/guide/http

> Most front-end applications communicate with backend services over the HTTP protocol. Modern browsers support two different APIs for making HTTP requests: the XMLHttpRequest interface and the fetch() API.
>
> With HttpClient, @angular/common/http provides a simplified API for HTTP functionality for use with Angular applications, building on top of the XMLHttpRequest interface exposed by browsers. Additional benefits of HttpClient include testability support, strong typing of request and response objects, request and response interceptor support, and better error handling via apis based on Observables.

Comment: I found some problem here , when i request for oauth token it automatically send at first OPTIONS request and thats why my emulator take the request as error , but browser doesn't work like that